# call new function inside a .map in react js hook

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to convert react class to react hook. In react class I use two classes one is to export and another one is called inside .map. This code is running.
While i do same code in react hook all good but hard to use (ListItem) as function inside the .map of export class.
FOR EXAMPLE:
this is called class.

```
import { Component } from "react";
const totalVec = new Array([]);
class ListItem extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: props.value.product.name,
        costo: props.value.product.costo,
        quantita: props.value.product.quantita,
        totale: 0
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.calcoloTotale = this.calcoloTotale.bind(this)
}
handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    }, this.calcoloTotale);
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
        { totale: this.state.costo * this.state.quantita },
        function () { totalVec[this.props.value.id] = this.state.totale; this.props.updateGlobalTotal(); });
}
calcoloTotale() {
    var Ltotale = this.state.costo * this.state.quantita;
    totalVec[this.props.value.id] = Ltotale;
    this.setState({ totale: Ltotale }, function () { this.props.updateGlobalTotal(); });
}
render() {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Nome..." /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="costo" value={this.state.costo} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Costo unitario..." /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantita" value={this.state.quantita} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Quantità..." /></td>
            <td className="total">{this.state.totale}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}}
```

AND THIS IS EXPORT CLASS

```
export default class Teste extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        counter: 2,
        lists: [
            {
                id: "0",
                product: {
                    name: "Example 1",
                    costo: "20",
                    quantita: "5"
                }
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                product: {
                    name: "Example 2",
                    costo: "50",
                    quantita: "2"
                }
            }
        ],
        totale: 0
    }
    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this)
    this.updateGlobalTotal = this.updateGlobalTotal.bind(this)
}
addRow() {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
    var listItem = { id: this.state.counter, product: { name: "", costo: "", quantita: "" } };
    var allItem = this.state.lists.concat([listItem])
    this.setState({ lists: allItem });
}
updateGlobalTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.counter; i++) {
        total += totalVec[i];
    }
    this.setState({ totale: total });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <h1>Dynamic Table</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    {this.state.lists.map((prodotto) =>
                        <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto} updateGlobalTotal={this.updateGlobalTotal} />
                    )}
                    <tr className="totalTr">
                        <td className="totalText">Total:</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td className="totalTR">{this.state.totale}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addRow}>+</button>
                Add Product
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

PROBLEM IS TO USE THIS

```
{this.state.lists.map((prodotto) =>
                        <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto} updateGlobalTotal={this.updateGlobalTotal} />
                    )}
```

IN REACT HOOK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function style for your class component, you may want to go through it and make necessary changes.

```
const Teste = (props) => {
     const [counter, setCounter] = useState(2)
     const [ lists, setLists ] = useState([
            {
                id: "0",
                product: {
                    name: "Example 1",
                    costo: "20",
                    quantita: "5"
                }
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                product: {
                    name: "Example 2",
                    costo: "50",
                    quantita: "2"
                }
            }
        ])

    const [totale, setTotale] = useState(0)
    const addRow = () => {
        let newCounter = counter+1
        setCounter(newCounter);
        var listItem = { id: newCounter, product: { name: "", costo: "", quantita: "" } };
        this.setLists([...lists, listItem])
    }

}

const updateGlobalTotal = () => {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        total += totalVec[i];
    }
    this.setTotale(total);
}

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <h1>Dynamic Table</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    { lists.map((prodotto) =>
                        <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto} updateGlobalTotal={updateGlobalTotal} />
                    )}
                    <tr className="totalTr">
                        <td className="totalText">Total:</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td className="totalTR">{totale}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={addRow}>+</button>
                Add Product
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I already did. This is not a problem.
The problem is 
{ lists.map((prodotto) =>
                        <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto} updateGlobalTotal={updateGlobalTotal} />
                    )}
While calling this function value didn't through its value and the ListItem function is not able to catch it.

Comment: well it's likely got to do with totalVec which I don't understand why you are using a global variable .